# Google plusone button shows its popup broken

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-plus-one

I used Google Plusone button in my web page and it appears with problem.
[image]

Please tell me what do I have to do ? The text is out of the box, and the left side of the box is not normal.

This is what I put in my code:

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>

<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Your CSS/HTML is interfering with the popup. Not much anyone can do without seeing it. Could you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that replicates the problem?

Comment: I can't @Juhana, because there are lots of codes both in HTML and CSS. But your answer made me sure that the problem belongs to an interfering ...
Thank you

Comment: @Juhana I could find the interfering point. I had set direction attribute for all tables incorrectly and this was affecting on google plus one button style. Thank you.